# Like operator condition in postgresql data issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have below data in the table

```
HJ-DEF-ABCF010-ABC18-09-17-D
GHJ-ABC-ABFV006-ABC18-09-18-R
OH-DEF-ABFCRT2037-ABC17-01-18-R
```

I want to populate the value in another column like

```
HJ-DEF-ABCF010-ABC18-09-17-D             BET
GHJ-ABC-ABFV006-ABD18-09-18-R            BET
OH-DEF-ABFCRT2037-ABCD17-01-18-R          BET
```

As the mapping for

```
ABC18 is BET   
ABD18 is BET
ABCD17 is BET
```

I was using the below sql query for that

```
select col1,case 
when col1 like '%-ABC[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET 
when col1 like '%-ABD[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET 
when col1 like '%-ABCD[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET
else - end form table
```

which is working fine in SQl sever but in Pogresql we can't use [1-2] to find out the expected digit in the position. Any suggestion or idea how to achieve in Posgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used with SIMILAR TO instead of like. select col1,case when col1 SIMILAR TO '%-AB([CD]|CD)[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET else - end form table thnx  @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3):

It works just fine. However, you think -- for some reason -- that `LIKE` supports character classes and other regular-expression-like features.  That is simply not true in Postgres, nor in any other database other than SQL Server, Sybase, and MS Access.

Just use regular expressions.

For the original version:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Customerid ~ '^[1-2][1-1]';
```

For the edited version:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Customerid ~ '[-].{3}[1-2]1';
```

Comment: If want to use like '%-__[1-2][0-9]%', any idea because % wouldn't work in this format

Comment: @RamanSingh . . . It is rude to change a question after it has been answered, especially in a way that invalidates answers.  Nevertheless, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I don't want to be rude(sorry for that)... I thought answer would be given for % replacement as well

Comment: @RamanSingh . . . Someone downvoted the answer, presumably because it no longer matched the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nope.  You picked up that downvote immediately.  I countered it.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually make your current logic work with `LIKE`, with a bit of effort:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Customerid LIKE '11%' OR Customerid LIKE '21%';
```

You seem to be using perhaps SQL Server or Sybase enhanced `LIKE` syntax.  Postgres does not support this, but it does support its own `~` regex operator.  See Gordon's answer for more on that.

The edit to your question can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Customerid ~ '-[^-]{3}[1-2]7';
```

### Demo

Comment: Correction in the where clause condition, please review it again

Comment: the  '-.{3}[1-2][7]-' solution wouldn't work if we have data like "XXXXX-XXX18-08-17-D". I want to ignore this data because valid one "XXXXX-XXX17-08-17-D"

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: If u change the condition '-.{3}[1-2][0-9]' with '-.{3}[1-2][7]'. In this case i don't want "XXXXX-XXX18-08-17-D" record as output because i want to compare the substring  XXX17 only here

Comment: Hi I have added the new Question with Scenario 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856576/like-operator-regex-not-working-as-expected-in-posgresql

Comment: Used with SIMILAR TO instead of like. select col1,case when col1 SIMILAR TO '%-AB([CD]|CD)[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET else - end form table thnx @Wiktor Stribiżew