# Like Operator regex not working as expected in Posgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have below data in the table

```
HJ-DEF-ABCF010-ABC18-09-17-D
GHJ-ABC-ABFV006-ABC18-09-18-R
OH-DEF-ABFCRT2037-ABC17-01-18-R
```

I want to populate the value in another column like

```
HJ-DEF-ABCF010-ABC18-09-17-D             BET
GHJ-ABC-ABFV006-ABD18-09-18-R            BET
OH-DEF-ABFCRT2037-ABCD17-01-18-R          BET
```

As the mapping for

```
ABC18 is BET   
ABD18 is BET
ABCD17 is BET
```

I was using the below sql query for that

```
select col1,case 
when col1 like '%-ABC[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET 
when col1 like '%-ABD[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET 
when col1 like '%-ABCD[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET
else - end form table
```

which is working fine in SQl sever but in Pogresql we can't use [1-2] to find out the expected digit in the position. Any suggestion or idea how to achieve in Posgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) that will be very close to what your `LIKE` does as it allows some POSIX regex patterns. You may even merge the patterns into 1 pattern:

```
select col1,case 
when col1 SIMILAR TO '%-AB([CD]|CD)[1-2][0-9]-%' then BET
else - end from table
```

**Details**

- `%` - any 0+ chars
- `-AB` - an `-AB` substring
- `([CD]|CD)` - either a `C`, or `D`, or `CD`
- `[1-2]` - `1` or `2`
- `[0-9]-` - a digit followed with `-`
- `%` - any text up to the end of the record.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression operator, `~`, and change the logic to:

```
select col1,
       (case when col1 ~ '-ABC[1-2][0-9]-' then BET 
             when col1 ~ '-ABD[1-2][0-9]-' then BET 
             when col1 ~ '-ABCD[1-2][0-9]-' then BET
             else -
        end) 
from table
```

Notes:

- Should `BET` and `-` be in single quotes?  They should be if you want strings.
- Regular expressions are not automatically anchored to the beginning of the string, so wildcards are not necessary.